# Are native Java methods equivalent to static Java methods?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am rewriting some native methods as regular Java methods.

Are native methods effectively static?  Or is there ever a case where they have an implicit 'this' parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `this`? You can split the method and implement the part doesn't need `this`. (i.e. You can implement the most basic functions in native code)

Comment: The `static` keyword still applies to `native` methods.  So...  no...  only the static ones are effectively static.

Comment: You don't have to be concerning on `this` since you can freely have whatever instruction you want in your function without it inside a native method.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Native methods can be `static` or non-`static`, just like regular Java methods.

Non-`static` native methods receive `this` reference, `static` ones receive a reference to containg class instead.

From [JNI Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html#wp715):

> Native Method Arguments
>
> The JNI interface pointer is the first argument to native methods. The JNI interface pointer is of type JNIEnv. The second argument differs depending on whether the native method is static or nonstatic. The second argument to a nonstatic native method is a reference to the object. The second argument to a static native method is a reference to its Java class.