# Android native method is invisible for Java

Tags: java, android, c++

I am struggling with very annoying error in my code. I have this error appearing over and over again:

```
    No implementation found for long com.oculus.gles3jni.GLES3JNILib.onCreate(android.app.Activity) 
(tried Java_com_oculus_gles3jni_GLES3JNILib_onCreate and 
Java_com_oculus_gles3jni_GLES3JNILib_onCreate__Landroid_app_Activity_2)
```

But in my file GLES3JNILib.java I have this:

```
package com.oculus.gles3jni;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Surface;

// Wrapper for native library

public class GLES3JNILib
{
    // Activity lifecycle
    public static native long onCreate( Activity obj );
    public static native void onStart( long handle );
    public static native void onResume( long handle );
    public static native void onPause( long handle );
    public static native void onStop( long handle );
    public static native void onDestroy( long handle );

    // Surface lifecycle
    public static native void onSurfaceCreated( long handle, Surface s );
    public static native void onSurfaceChanged( long handle, Surface s );
    public static native void onSurfaceDestroyed( long handle );

    // Input
    public static native void onKeyEvent( long handle, int keyCode, int action );
    public static native void onTouchEvent( long handle, int action, float x, float y );
}
```

So I am not sure what is wrong. It is there but still I can't start my app. In my cpp code the implementation is:

```
jlong Java_com_oculus_gles3jni_GLES3JNILib_onCreate( JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jobject activity )
{
...
}
```

Does someone see what I am missing, or doing wrong? Is it possible that this is because I don't have h file for my cpp?

Comment: Because the native declaration is `static`, shouldn't the 'C' implementaion be `Java_com_oculus_gles3jni_GLES3JNILib_onCreate( JNIEnv * env, jobject activity )`?  As there is no implied "this" reference for static methods.  Did you generate the "C" header file with `javah`?

Comment: @RichardCritten actually the second parameter should be a jclass for static methods as noted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253914/are-native-java-methods-equivalent-to-static-java-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have generated the C code and then changed the Java native method declaration to `static` without re-running `javah`.

Or you didn't run it at all and tried to wing it. Don't do that.

The correct signature has `jclass` for the second parameter, but don't take my word for it: rerun `javah` and adjust your .c file accordingly.

NB your .c file should #include your .h file.

Answer (score -1):

Did you forget to load the library?

```
public class GLES3JNILib
{
   static {
      try {
        System.loadLibrary("libGLES3JNILib");
      } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
          // do something helpful here
      }
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: @EJP what do you mean? The error he lists is *exactly* the error you get if you don't load the library beforehand? Sure, there are other reasons too, but this is fairly common and fits the circumstances shown.

Comment: It says it tried two other native methods. Where did it get those from? How could it try anything without having loaded a library to try them from?