# JNI function error in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-native-interface, vtk

I'm in trouble with this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tehPt.jpg

I'm using the VTK sample code and JNI isn't working and I don't know what to do. I compiled all the libraries and when I try the app on phone, the app stop.

What can I do?

Edit: Errors: http://pastebin.com/rf7vFVT8

Comment: can you post native side code?

Comment: https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/tree/master/Examples/Android/VolumeRender

Comment: I followed this instruction to build it: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/Linux and I'm using Qt5

Comment: I just saw the write "Add android vr example and fixes to support it" on github but I don't know which example is.

Comment: Those are the errors: http://pastebin.com/rf7vFVT8

Comment: Could you show your error message? Without those information, it's very hard to figure out what happened. The error message in your picture is fine,  your JNI function might be implemented in another form.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rf7vFVT8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.

The building of the library was incorrect and I followed this guide http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/Linux

Answer (score 0):

The second arg for static native method should be `jclass`, not `jobject`.

See [Are native Java methods equivalent to static Java methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253914/are-native-java-methods-equivalent-to-static-java-methods) for more details.

> Native Method Arguments
>
> The JNI interface pointer is the first argument to native methods. The JNI interface pointer is of type JNIEnv. The second argument differs depending on whether the native method is static or nonstatic. The second argument to a nonstatic native method is a reference to the object. The second argument to a static native method is a reference to its Java class.

Comment: where did you see the jobject? I can't find it

Comment: In the Github page (https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/tree/master/Examples/Android/VolumeRender) they say that I have to add the android vr example but I don't know which example they mean.